# Connect RC522 RFID UART reader/writer to RX/TX

Tags: serial, uart, rfid

I'm trying to hook up my Elechouse v1.1 RFID UART module to my Raspberry Pi. I haven't been able to find any example code or guides on this, but I'm sure it's possible. Hooking up this module to an Arduino and opening the Serial Monitor works fine. I can read cards and so on by uploading [their code](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/13.56MHZ_RFID_Module/RFID%20with%20Arduino.pdf) to my Arduino.

Would something like this be possible? It's a simple module with only TX, RX, GND, and 3.3v or 5v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elechouse v1.1 RFID uses MRFC522 chip and has an option to connect using SPI or UART.

The Arduino examples on their site uses UART and it looks simple enough that you can port it to python.

Once you have connected the module to the Pi (the module seems to use 5V UART so you'll need level converter like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) so that it is safe to use with the Pi), you have to write 0x02 to the module and wait to read data back from the module whenever you bring a Mifare card close to the module.

The module also has SPI pins broken out which are 3.3V logic and compatible with the Pi. There are several examples ([here](https://github.com/mab5vot9us9a/MFRC522-python), [here](https://github.com/rasplay/MFRC522-python) and [here](https://www.sunfounder.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_Use_an_RFID_RC522_on_Raspberry_Pi))to use it with the Pi, so I would recommend you to solder the SPI headers and try those examples out.

Comment: Would you recommend SPI or UART? I don't have any headers long enough laying around right now.

Comment: I would say SPI. Even though it is harder, there are libraries available which should make your life easier. You should be fine with normal though-hole headers and jumper wires

Comment: How did you know you had to write 0x02 to the module? Where can I find the other available commands?

Comment: @RocketTwitch The command for writing 0x02 is given in the manufacturer's tutorial [here](https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/13.56MHZ_RFID_Module/RFID%20with%20Arduino.pdf). They have not added any more commands. There is source code available on their site that you can look at to find the other commands. The difference in this module is that instead of exposing the chip directly, they have a micro-controller sitting in between talking with the chip, so you would need the source code of what runs on the MCU to know the commands. You should reach out to the manufacturer.